# Firebug not displaying 302 response

Tags: http, firebug, http-status-code-302

Does anyone know why I can't see an HTTP request that results in a 302, on Firebug's Net panel? I've got the Persist flag switched on, and the following URI that the 302 points to is shown. It's solely this one 302 that is not showing up.

I've run the same steps in Google Chrome, and Web Inspector shows both the 302, and the URI the 302 points to.

Comment: I've seen this, looks like a regression.  Maybe explains why the author jumped ship to Google :D

Comment: This seems to be happening if the redirect url is on another domain. I'm reporting it to firebug right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this using Firefox 13.0.1 together with Firebug 1.9.2.
Here's a test case for this:

http://www.janodvarko.cz/firebug/tests/1681/Issue1681.htm

The related Firebug issue is [issue 1681](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1681).

Is that working for you now?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Net tab's down arrow, and check Disable Browser Cache.